# Given a $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is there a $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(f) = 0$ with $g \neq 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Given a $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is there a $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(f) = 0$?

I would like to solve the problem myself but don't know how to start.

Point of this question; I have a recurrence relation of the form:
$z_n(x) = z_{n-1}(x) + g(z_{n-1}(x))$  and I want to know if there is a $g$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n(x)$ can approximate any function in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ arbitrarily-well.

Let us assume that is true and 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n(x) - f(x)| \mathrm{d}x= 0\:;
$$
this would imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(z_n(x)) = g(f(x)) =0$

Comment: What about $f = f_n = 0$?

Comment: I should clarify, you are right!

Comment: Ah, but you still have $f = 0$, and $f_n \to 0$. For example, if $f_n(x) = 1/n$ for all $x$. Indeed, if $f$ is constant (not necessarily $0$), this will be easily satisfied

Comment: You are correct again; i want a non-constant $f$

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)\in[0,1]$ for all $x$.

Comment: By the by, this is a great lesson in how to start questions like these: try some fairly trivial examples. At worst, you'll refine your question into something more interesting.

Comment: On another note, is there anything in particular behind this question? Did it come from somewhere?

Comment: I made some mistakes in the question and just updated it.

Comment: You should definitely include such context from the very start. Don't wait for everyone to pick at a half-baked question; give the full thing!